# Get several elements with BeautifulSoup 4 from many pages

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have several pages to scrape and I was getting a part of html code (from each page) where I want to get another part of code. So after:

```
reqw = [requests.get(i) for i in ds['for_change']]
soups = [BeautifulSoup(i.content, 'html.parser') for i in reqw]
```

I started to collect the parts of code that I need from every page:

```
li = []
for i in range(len(soups)):
    li.append(soups[i].find_all('li', attrs={'itemprop':'application'}))
```

The result is:

```
li[1]
>>>[<li itemprop="application" itemscope="" repeat="">
 >>><span itemprop="filingDate">2016-06-30</span>
 >>><span itemprop="countryCode">US</span>
 >>><span itemprop="applicationNumber">US15/199,528</span>
 >>><a href="/patent/US10059683B2/en"><span itemprop="documentId">patent/US10059683B2/en</span></a>
 >>><span itemprop="legalStatusCat">active</span>
 >>><span itemprop="legalStatus">Active</span>
 >>></li>, 
 >>>next element that is similar to previuos, ...]
```

When I start to try to get something from this list, like

```
li[1].find_all('a')
```

I am getting error

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

My task is to get the next two rows

```
<span itemprop="countryCode">US</span>
<a href="/patent/US10059683B2/en"><span itemprop="documentId">patent/US10059683B2/en</span></a>
```

And to be concrete only

```
US
patent/US10059683B2/en
```

Probably I can use Beautiful Soup to my list again and then make a few more extractions to get what I need. But I believe that there is some easier possibility to do that. Thanks for any help. An example of the links that I am working with is here https://patents.google.com/patent/JP2020037596A/en

Comment: `li[1]` is a list of `li` tags. Which `li` tag do you want to do `find_all` on?

Comment: @Chase, one li tag corresponds to one page that I am scrapping. I am scrapping several pages so I need info from all li's that I have

Comment: actually, *each* page is returning **multiple** `li` elements. You have a *list of lists* of `li` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for li_tag in li:
    span = li_tag.find('span', {'itemprop':'countryCode'}).text
    links = li_tag.find_all('a')
    print(span)
    [print(link.text) for link in links]
```

Output:

```
US
patent/US10059683B2/en
```

Comment: it is working! But is it possible to get that result not from li list but from the original code? Like li, span, links for one extraction?

Comment: Can u elaborate more on it so that I can help you?

Comment: First I am scraping soups[i].find_all('li', attrs={'itemprop':'application'}) (1st action). Then I am going to use the code that you have purpose (2nd action). And it is working. But can I get all li, links and spans in one action?

Comment: U can simplify it. Just change `for li_tag in li:` to `for li_tag in soups[i].find_all('li', attrs={'itemprop':'application'})`